# Combine tail -F and json

Tags: json, tail

My log files have one json object per line.
I use [json][1] to get a human readable output via

```
cat mylog.log | json -a field1 field2
```

Now I would like to have

```
tail -F mylog.log | json -a field1 field2
```

for a continuous output. But this seems not to
work, the shell simply hangs. If I use `&|` to
avoid buffering issues, the output is as if
I only run `cat`.

`mylog.log` looks like this:

```
{"field1": entry1a, "field2": entry2a, "field3": entry3a}
{"field1": entry1b, "field2": entry2b, "field3": entry3b}
```

Any suggestions?

[1] https://github.com/trentm/json

Comment: `&|` ? what kind of shell is this?

Comment: `zsh`, but I think it does not do what I thought it does ...

Comment: You might want to take a look at https://bitbucket.org/bartswen/bsonify/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's looks like `json` [first loads the whole `stdin` into a buffer and only then processes the data](https://github.com/trentm/json/blob/master/lib/jsontool.js#L565), but you should still be able to achieve stream processing by calling it for each of the lines added to the log file, something like this:

```
tail -F mylog.log | while read line; do echo "$line" | json -a field1 field2; done
```

Comment: I had some json with escaped backslashes - class:"path\\to\\class".  To preserve these, I had to change the read statement to read -r line, which preserves them