# Read .log file of a docker container that is not in the host

Tags: docker, logging, docker-logs

I have a `.log` JSON log file of a container running on a different computer and I want to figure out what went wrong. I don't have access to the computer but have the logs. I can view the logs in a text editor but I want to view it like the output of `docker logs`.

Is there a way I can view the logs in a human-readable way? `docker logs` documentation only accepts `CONTAINER` as input param. Some solutions like [Dozzle](https://github.com/amir20/dozzle) also seem to be real-time log viewers and I couldn't find a log viewer that accepts a file input.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried using `tail -f` on the log file?

Comment: Do you mean `tail -f logfile.log` or something with `docker logs --tail`? The `tail -f` command just shows the log file as text, which I can already do in a text editor/viewer. I'm trying to get a nice looking output.

Comment: I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9667675/combine-tail-f-and-json).